# Как сделать пробел после вывода каждого значения массива

Tags: массивы, php, mysql

```
do   
    {
    echo  $row['fio_student' ];
    echo  $row['groupst'];
    echo  $row['starosta'];
    echo  $row['info_st']. '<br>';
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

Comment: echo "anything_1"." ";
echo "anything_2"." ";

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: @VladD, @klopp, а если не нужны все записи? Тогда не подойдет.

Comment: >а если не нужны все записи

1) "Если, конечно, select позволяет"

2) Условия изложены вполне ясно: "после вывода каждого значения массива"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо:

```
echo "{$row['fio_student']} {$row['groupst']}...";
```

Хотя в данном случае будет не так читабельно. Но можно же переделать:

```
do {
    $output = $row[..];
    $output .= " {$row[..]}";
    ...
    echo $output;
} while ...
```

Answer (score 1):

А можно и так :)

```
echo implode( ' ', array_values($row) );
```

Если, конечно, select позволяет. BTW, пробел или `&nbsp;`?